# How can I unzip very large zip file (>6gb) in Google Colab notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, unzip

I am unable to unzip a file downloaded into current directory due to the error:

```
zipfiles that span multiple disks are not supported
```

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following command:

```
!apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Use the following command to unzip it:

```
!7za x FileName
```

The above code should help you out to unzip large files(>5GB) in google colab.

Comment: Don't do `!7za e FileName.zip` you should do `!7za x FileName.zip` otherwise you will end will all files on same directory. the `x` flag preserves directory structure.

Comment: Yeah, that would be an even better thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although not in Google Colab, but in a similar service at my local institution at the Göttingen Library. The previous solution did not work for me, because I did not have the authorization to install new programs on the server. Instead, I used directly the function `unzip` from Linux:

`!unzip your_zip_file.zip`

That worked for me!