# unzip large Files - Google Colab Notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I try to unzip a zip file with 9000 pictures (approx. 60 kb per picture) ) in Colab Notebook and always get the message:
Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines.

I first create the directory in the Colab Notebook and get the zipp file, then I want to unzip it in the home directory

> HOME = '/home' %cd /home
>
> SOURCE_DIR=  os.path.join(HOME, 'data')
>
> !gdown --id 'Google Drive
>   ID'
>
> !unzip '/home/cat.zip' -d '/home'

do I have to use another command?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721458/streaming-output-truncated-to-the-last-5000-lines-google-collab. It's probably best to use pathlib instead of os.path, by the way. Also, isn't `gdown` a third-party tool? There appear to already be multiple options for getting data from Drive, documented by the Colab team: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=c2W5A2px3doP.

Comment: connecting to the drive is not my goal, since I am changing the data, I would like to work with a copy. The fastest way is zipp files. The question is, why is the data cut off at all?

Comment: for all who have the same problem, .... the solution is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590747/how-can-i-unzip-very-large-zip-file-6gb-in-google-colab-notebook

Comment: Is the actual data being cut off, or simply the printed output? I suspect it might be the latter.

Comment: I have checked it. It is actually only not shown in the printed edition. When you're new, it's really confusing ;-)